# How to join table A to B to find all the entries in A whose intervals contain entries in B?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am comparing two tables `A` and `B` of log entry intervals, i.e. each record in a table is the first log entry and then another, for a given user, like this:

```
+--------+----------+--------+-----------+--------+
| userID |  date1   | logID1 |   date2   | logID2 |
+--------+----------+--------+-----------+--------+
|    235 | 1/3/2013 |     45 | 1/7/2013  |     48 |
|    235 | 4/6/2013 |     64 | 4/12/2013 |     73 |
|    462 | 1/4/2013 |     40 | 1/16/2013 |     50 |
+--------+----------+--------+-----------+--------+
```

I want to build a join query that links every record in `A` to all the records in `B` based on `userID`, where `A` contains `B` in either dates:

```
a.date1<=b.date1, a.date2>=b.date2
```

or IDs:

```
a.logID1<=b.logID1, a.logID2>=b.logID2
```

I want to return all records in `A`, regardless of whether or not there is a contained interval in `B`.

At first glance it seems like this would work:

```
select * from a
left join b
on
a.userID=b.userID
where
(a.date1<=b.date1 or a.logID1<=b.logID1)
and
(a.date2>=b.date2 or a.logID2>=b.logID2)
or
b.userID is null
```

But the problem is that if there is a record in `A` that has a matching `userID` in `B` but the `A` record does not contain the `B` record, the join will occur but the record will be filtered out by the WHERE condition, so the `A` record will not appear in the results.

If I try to resolve this by moving the WHERE conditions to the JOIN clause as follows:

```
select * from a
left join b
on
a.userID=b.userID
and
(a.date1<=b.date1 or a.logID1<=b.logID1)
and
(a.date2>=b.date2 or a.logID2>=b.logID2)
```

then I get this error message:

```
JOIN expression not supported.
```

I assume this means Access can't have nested OR conditions in the JOIN criteria.

What can I do to return a list of `A`, joined to their contained `B` where applicable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all records in `a`, then put the condition in the `on` clause.  `where` has strange effects.  So try:

```
select *
from a left join
     b
     on a.userID = b.userID and
        (a.date1<=b.date1 or a.logID1<=b.logID1)
        (a.date2>=b.date2 or a.logID2>=b.logID2);
```

Comment: as I mentioned in my question, this gives a `JOIN expression not supported` error; I don't think Access allows nested OR  operations in JOIN clauses.

Comment: never mind, this does work. the error message was due to inconsistent aliasing in my original query.

Comment: @sigil . . . Phew.  Access has a lot of strange limitations, but I didn't think this was one of them.